# Python pymysql datetime.datetime tuple to timestamp

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, pymysql

I have code that selects the max timestamp from a MySQL db as follows:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT max(played_at) FROM 
testDB.Log;")
max_date = cursor.fetchall()
```

it returns a datetime.datetime object like this:

```
((datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 11, 44, 5),),)
```

I need it to return a timestamp in the format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

I have tried using strptime(), datetime(), and strftime() but each time I get the error "tuple has no object (insert one of the three)"

How can I get the format i want?

Comment: `strftime` is just fine, the only problem is that you need to apply it to an index of the tuple, not the whole tuple itself. `max_date[0][0]` gets you at the datetime itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cursor is returning the database row as a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), you need to access individual columns values using square bracket notation. Columns are indexed from 0.

example:

```
print(max_date[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Additionally cursor.fetchall() returns a list of tuples. You could use cursor.fetchone() in this particular instance given select(max) would always return one row.